# Add link to open the Next badge page on the profile activity page

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges, profile-page, badge-progress

The "Next tag badge" and "Newest" badge widget have this button:

> [image: Next tag badge] [image: Newest]

But "Next badge" widget doesn't:

> [image]

Can you add the button on this popup to open the badge page?

Answer (score 2):

Those are two different buttons; if you've earned the badge (your 'Popular Question' screenshot), the popup will always show a "Learn more >" button which will take you to your personal badge page where you can see how often you've earned that particular badge.

The popup related to the progress will show a "Go get it >" button *if there's a meaningful page to show you*. For example, when tracking the [Socratic badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/244/socratic), it will take you to the [Ask a Question page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask):

[image]

Other badges might take you to other pages. However, TPTB have decided that there's no good target page for the Marshal badge. Now that I think of it, the First Posts review queue might be a viable option; on some sites, I cast quite a few Not An Answer flags and close flags for them. There's a precedent for linking to review queues; if you have enough reputation to edit posts, the "Go get it" button for the Copy Editor badge takes you to the Low Quality Posts review queue.